# jQuery: Scroll events and one()

Tags: jquery, scroll, conditional-statements, jquery-waypoints

I have a few conditional events depending on scroll position of a page. Everything works swell, except the last event that I need to fire **only once**. Here is my code:

```
function curScroll() {      
    var scrollX = $(window).scrollTop();
    var pointA = $('#pointA').offset().top;
    var pointB = $('#pointB').offset().top;

    if (scrollX < pointA) {
        $('#something').removeClass('middle').addClass('top');  
    } else if ((scrollX >= pointA) && (scrollX < pointB)) {
        $('#something').addClass('middle').removeClass('top');
    } else if (scrollX >= pointB) {
        $('#something').removeClass('middle top');
        // DO SOMETHING JUST ONCE, NOT EVERY TIME USER SCROLLS TO THE POINT
    }
}
```

I assume the one() function is the way. The problem is the required "event" parameter.

So should I attach custom trigger() that fires each time user scrolls to pointB? Is there another way?

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't get your question.

Comment: putvande, my original code is quite complex (lots of animates, fadeIns, etc.), I tried to simplify it to explain my problem. However very obvious sollution was to add a flag, as Roy suggested. Thank you!

Comment: you can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gFXcm/5/ This way all three events fire only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a flag to indicate when it was done?

```
// DO SOMETHING JUST ONCE, NOT EVERY TIME USER SCROLL TO THE POINT
if (!('doneIt' in curScroll)) {
  curScroll.doneIt = true;
  // ...do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Uh-oh, I just suffered a severe case of overthinking the problem. :) Thank you, it obviously works.